# Unable to start server when I use Eureka and actuator

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using Spring boot version 2.2.0.M4. When I am adding dependencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

while starting server it fails to start with below mentioned error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
    org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.health.DiscoveryCompositeHealthIndicator.<init>(DiscoveryCompositeHealthIndicator.java:42)
```

Comment: You can now use Spring Cloud `Hoxton.M1` with Boot `2.2.0.M4`. See the update in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way of working with Spring Cloud projects versioning is using the `dependencyManagement` plugin and release trains versions rather than passing versions of separate artifacts manually.

You can get a correct pom generated automatically (with all the correct versions) at [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/).

On the date that question was posted, a version of Spring Cloud supporting Spring Boot `2.2.x` has not been released yet. The latest Spring Cloud release version available is `Greenwich.SR2`, that supports Spring Boot `2.1.6.RELEASE`.

**UPDATE**: Spring Cloud `Hoxton.M1` that supports Spring Boot `2.2.0.M4` was released on 3rd July 2019. You can now use it and also generate correct build files with this version from [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/).

Answer (score 1):

For the following dependency:

```
<parent>    
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>    
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository --> 
</parent>
```

The Following spring cloud version worked for me.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```